# Problem UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, camera, xcode4

Hey guys, 
I know it has been asked more often, but the answers to their questions don't seem to apply here.

My didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method doesn't get called :(

Here is my code:

The .h-file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface DevicePictureController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

    UIImageView *photo;
    UIButton *selectPhoto;
    UIButton *takePhoto;
    NSMutableDictionary *listLocations;
    NSMutableDictionary *listDevices;
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *photo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *selectPhoto;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *takePhoto;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *picker;

-(IBAction)selectPicture:(id)sender;
@end
```

The .m-file:
    #import "DevicePictureController.h"

```
@implementation DevicePictureController
@synthesize photo, selectPhoto, takePhoto, picker;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    listLocations = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    listDevices = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
}

-(IBAction)selectPicture:(id)sender {

    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if ((UIButton *)sender == selectPhoto)  {

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickController:(UIImagePickerController *)picked didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picked dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Geselecteerd: %@", [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]);
    //photo = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [photo setImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]];
}

@end
```

So, my album or my camera gets loaded/activated properly, but when I click 'Use' or the photo, I only see the 2 buttons and an emtpy UIImageView after the view is dismissed. 
'photo' is connected to UIImageView, 'selectPhoto' and 'takePhoto' are connected to their buttons, 'selectPicture' is connected to both the buttons' Touch Up Inside-action.
Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your delegete method.

It should be

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

but you have

```
- (void)imagePickController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: I don't know if I should buy myself some new glasses or just head into bed. Thank mate (answer can be accepted after 10 minutes, somehow)

Comment: You beat me to it by about 50 seconds. So avoiding duplicate answer and voting up your answer

Comment: :P thanks. Spotting someone elses typo is a great way to start the day. I'm sure that by the end of it I'll be wallowing in my own buggy code.

Comment: Perhaps when I wake up again, I can return the favor ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
listLocations = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
listDevices = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: just replace ur viewDidLoad with this one. set picker.delegate = self;
so it will call its delegate methods didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo called